# Вызов функций сразу, без вложения в анонимные

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, javascript

Можно ли в данном примере вставить вызов функций сразу, без вложения в анонимные?

```
    var parentLI = $("#nav .parent");

parentLI.hoverIntent(function() {
    showUL($(this));
}, function() {
    hideUL($(this));
});
```

Comment: По [этой ссылке][1] можно посмотреть все возможные виды функций и их вызовы без jquery


  [1]: http://learn.javascript.ru/function-declaration-expression

Answer (score 1):

Нет, потому-что функции `showUL` и `hideUL` ожидают объект jQuery, а если вы поставите ссылки:

```
 parentLI.hoverIntent(showUL, hideUL);
```

в эти функции придет, видимо, `HTMLElement`.